# New Lines at the End of Code Files

Tags: version-control, formatting, conventions

I've noticed what seems to be a very strong convention among IDEs and code-oriented text editors. Almost any time I create a new code file, regardless of the language, IDE, or platform on which I create the file, they almost always have a trailing new line at the end.

For example:

- C++ and C# class wizards in Visual Studio always have this new line after the last curly brace.
- The nano editor in the Linux terminal does not allow you to remove the last new line.
- Git version control makes a specific point to point out files which do not end with a new line.

So, why is this a common practice? I've never had a problem with scripts where I intentionally remove this new line. Does it have significance for legacy purposes?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In many cases, it can simplify text processing tools - there doesn't need to be special handling for the last line that might or might not have a new line; all lines can just be treated equivalently. That said, most tools still have to be prepared to deal with the case where there isn't a newline anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you would be hard pressed to find a modern editor or compiler which has issues with unterminated lines, this wasn't always the case. If you need to manipulate your source code programmatically, there are probably still e.g. `sed` implementations out there which are buggy in this respect.

At a minimum, you should make a conscious decision about which way you want things; if you are authoring, say, a company coding style guideline, it probably makes sense to require or recommend source files to have a final newline, because it helps avoid religious wars and supports the lowest common denominator.